# "Small change" vs "Loose change"

Tags: meaning

When we are talking about money, is there any difference between "small change" and "loose change"? It seems that both mean "coins of little value."

These are examples from [Oxford Dictionaries](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/change_2):

> I didn't have any small change (= coins of low value) to leave as a tip.

> He puts his loose change in a money box for the children.

Answer (score 6):

"Small change" can refer to coins of low value, or to paper money of low value, or metaphorically to anything of low relative worth; a couple of $50 bills is "small change" to someone looking for a $200,000 payment, for example.

"Loose change" specifically refers to all of the coins that you happen to have in your pockets or purse that are not rolled or bundled up; if you got two quarters back from a purchase and just dropped them into your front pocket, for example, that's loose change.  If you put the quarters into a sleeve for making a "roll of quarters", then they aren't loose anymore.  (In a coin purse or a wallet pouch, they're probably still able to rattle about and make noise, which is a key element of being considered "loose", I think.)

Comment: I don't completely agree with this definition of "loose change." I don't think it's literally change that is loose. I think it's just the little spare change that people carry around with them on a day to day basis. You could have loose change in your coin purse or in the coin pocket of your wallet.

Comment: I agree with @Daniel. It definitely isn't loose change if you put them in a roll-sleeve-thing, but I think it's still loose change if it's in your wallet/coin flap.  That's perhaps not where the term originated, but I think it's what it has come to mean now. Regardless, this is a very useful answer, so +1 :)

Comment: @Daniel and Wendikidd, Yeah, I think I have to agree with you after all.  Updated to try to explain looseness better.

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with its ability to rattle around. It's all about being easily accessible. If you have a cup of coins at your house, but you don't carry it around with you, that is not loose change even if the coins can rattle around in the cup.

Comment: On that I think we are going to have to disagree; a couple of coins in a cup qualifies as "loose change" to me.  (a cup filled with coins, on the other hand, is not.)